# Many-to-many SELECT divided into multiple rows for some reason

Tags: join, select, many-to-many, firebird

I have two tables joined via third in a many-to-many relationship. To simplify:

Table A
ID-A (int)
Name (varchar)
Score (numeric)

Table B
ID-B (int)
Name (varchar)

Table AB
ID-AB (int)
A (foreign key ID-A)
B (foreign key ID-B)

What I want is to display the B-Name and a sum of the "Score" values of all the As belonging to the given B. However, the following code:

```
WITH "Data" AS(
SELECT "B."."Name" As "BName", "A"."Name", "Score"
FROM "AB"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "A" ON "AB"."A" = "A"."ID-A"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" ON "AB"."B" = "B"."ID-B")

SELECT "BName", SUM("Score") AS "Total"
FROM "Data"
GROUP BY "Name", "Score"
ORDER BY "Total" DESC
```

The results display several rows for every "BName" with the "score" divided into semingly random increments between these rows. For example, if the desired result for Johnny is 12 and for April it's 25, the query may shows something like:

Johnny | 7

Johnny | 3

Johnny | 2

April | 19

April | 5

April | 1

etc.

Even after trying to nest the query and doing another SELECT with SUM("Score"), the results are the same. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Score` from the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT BName, SUM(Score) AS Total
FROM Data
GROUP BY BName
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

The purpose of your query is to summarize by name, so name alone should appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  By also including the score, you will get a record in the output for each unique name/score combination.

Comment: Without "Score" in the GROUP BY, Firebird throws an error at me, saying I can't use SUM.

Comment: Oops! My mistake, fixin'

Comment: @eworm It seems unlikely that "Without "Score" in the GROUP BY" the DBMS "throws an error at me, saying I can't use SUM.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out my problem. Indeed, I had to GROUP BY "Name" only, but Firebird I thought wasn't letting me do that. Turns out it was just a typo. Oops.

Comment: Can you mark my answer correct, given that I said basically the same thing?

Comment: It might be more helpful to specify what that typo was.